# Xaml(silverlight) to html5 conversion

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, xaml, silverlight

We have a Silverlight project running well and good, but now our client wants to have it converted to HTML5.

So we go with xaml to html5 conversion and use it in c#.

Analysis and research I have done so far:

1. The Microsoft [XAML to HTML Conversion Demo](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/XAML-to-HTML-Conversion-ed25a674/sourcecode?fileId=17340&pathId=1780213378) but there are plenty of issues with that code
2. Watched a [channel9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/HTM14) video of an Italian guy explaining some features for Silverlight and HTML5
3. Looked at the [Fayde XAML engine written in Javascript that renders on the HTML5 Canvas](http://fayde.wsick.com/) but that seems of no use

What can we do?

We don't have any conversion class so the best approach would be to go with comparing templates one by one and replace. We could write code for that or can XSLT do the trick?

What I would be requiring here is a proper step by step guidance to proceed further.
What should be my execution plan?

Is there any way other than comparing xaml to html5/Knockout.js one by one

Here I am displaying my sample code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Capitation.ElectronicFileGeneration"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:Mtabcal="clr-namespace:MtabCalender;assembly=MtabCalender"
    xmlns:MtabCombobox="clr-namespace:MtabCombobox;assembly=MtabCombobox"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
               xmlns:controlsToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit" 
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="1000" xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk">


    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRootTop">
        <StackPanel>

            <controlsToolkit:BusyIndicator x:Name="SampleIndicator"  Grid.ColumnSpan="3"   >
                <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Height="600">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />

                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border  CornerRadius="15" Margin="0,0,0,410" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="994">
                        <!--<Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="White"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#BED9F0" Offset="0.633"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>-->
                    </Border>
                    <TextBlock Height="17" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="81,21,0,0" Name="tbCheckprefix" Text="Check Prefix:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" />
                    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="167,19,0,0" Name="txtCheckPrefix" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="46" Grid.Row="1" MaxLength="4"  />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Height="17" Name="tbCheckNoF2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,53,0,0" Text="&lt;F2>" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                    <TextBlock Height="17" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="74,53,0,0" Name="tbCheckNo" Text="Check Number:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" />
                    <MtabCombobox:Combobox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="169,51,0,0" Name="cbCheckNumber"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" DropDownClosed="cbCheckNumber_DropDownClosed" Grid.Row="1">
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="IN" IsSelected="True"  />
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="NOT IN"  />
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="BETWEEN"  />
                    </MtabCombobox:Combobox>

                    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="269,52,0,0" Name="txtFCheckNo" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130" Grid.Row="1" MaxLength="8" KeyDown="txtNumeric_KeyDown" />
                    <Button Content="" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="411,52,0,0" Name="btnCheckNo"  Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="23" Click="btnCheckNo_Click" >
                        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                            <ToolTip Content="Search"></ToolTip>
                        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Image Source="Images/Search-icon.png"  Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                    </Button>
                    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="446,52,0,0" Name="txtTCheckNo" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130" Grid.Row="1" MaxLength="8" KeyDown="txtNumeric_KeyDown" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                    <Button Content="" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="588,52,0,0" Name="btnToCheckNo"  Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="23" Click="btnToCheckNo_Click" Visibility="Collapsed">
                        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                            <ToolTip Content="Search"></ToolTip>
                        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Image Source="Images/Search-icon.png"  Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                    </Button>
                    <TextBlock Height="17" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="309,87,0,0" Name="tbBank" Text="Bank Name:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" />
                    <MtabCombobox:Combobox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="381,83,0,0" Name="cbBankNames" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="152">
                        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="15">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Code}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Descr}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </MtabCombobox:Combobox>
                    <Button Content="Generate IIF File" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="60,128,0,0" Name="btnGenerateFile" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="157" Click="btnGenerateFile_Click" ></Button>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Height="17" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,85,0,0"  Name="tbPD"  VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" Width="7" TextAlignment="Left" Text="*" Foreground="Red"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="60,85,0,0" Name="tbPaidDate" Text="Check Run Date:" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    <!--<sdk:DatePicker Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="168,85,0,0" Name="dpPaidDate" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" KeyDown="dpPaidDate_KeyDown" />-->
                    <Mtabcal:MtabCalender Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="168,85,0,0" Name="dpPaidDate" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"  />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Height="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="246,156,0,0" Name="tbMessage" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="468" Foreground="#FF0011C5" FontWeight="Bold" />

                </Grid>
            </controlsToolkit:BusyIndicator>

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: This won't be an easy task. One approach would be to use HTML5 Custom Elements - an HTML5 Web Components technology. In an initial migration, XSLT could be used to add 'name-' prefixes to replace namespaces and style these using a CSS file using CSS styles such as: 'display:table' - see http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/ for more on Custom Elements

Comment: @LostCoder So [edit] your question and put in a link to the "channel9 video of an Italian guy..."

Comment: The best way would be something similar to Silverlight over WebGL in the future, when WebGL is widely adopted. Otherwise, I personally don't believe XAML to HTML conversion is feasible, considering the fact that XAML is much more complicated. Rewrite is currently the best approach.

Comment: @Lex li: Well you`re right I feel that too, but right now I choose to use HTML5 for ui and KnockoutJS(KO) for javscript handling, I am very much impressed by the KO functionality two way binding and observable method. If the conversion will run on the two/ three pages then i will plan out to find the pattern and build one utility to do the same for the rest of the project.

Answer (score 2):

You may go for [C#/XAML for HTML5](http://cshtml5.com)

It is currently in beta stage, and incomplete, but it will save much time.